# Getting connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 error when running supertest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, supertest, superagent

My student got a `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80` error when running the following test:

```js
it("returns status code 200", () => {
  return request(app)
    .get("./about")
    .expect(200)
});
```

My student is using `supertest` for HTTP assertions on `superagent` requests. They are using `jest` as their test runner.

### Background

One of my students encountered this problem and we eventually found the error to be a small typo in the route.

Since it took us a while to find the solution, I thought of posting the question here in case anyone else who has the same problem can find the solution easily.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the route, remove the `.` in `"./about"` to `"/about"` and it should now work as expected.

Your code should now look like this:

```js
it("returns status code 200", () => {
  return request(app)
    .get("/about")
    .expect(200)
});
```